# How to destroy injected service in angularjs cache?

Tags: angularjs, caching, angularjs-injector

We all know that in AngularJS `service` are singletons. Since then when you do this `$injector.get('foo')` you will get an instance of this service and its constructor would be invoked + object would be added into injector's cache for the reason because it is the singleton.

Anyway, are there any methods that I can utilize for removing service in that cache for re-creating service again? Using `factory` solves this but anyway.

Comment: Why you really need to remove it from cache? Is enough for you to invoke again the service using a custom reset function? `this.reset = function(){ myService() }` I believe that the result will be same. I could provide an answer if that fit for you.

Comment: Sure. move it to the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To reset a service, you can expose a function that invoke the service again.

<kbd>[PLUNKER](https://plnkr.co/edit/eGUPDccO2ShKQ2LIE9n2?p=preview)</kbd>

**Service**

```
app.service('MyService', MyService);

function MyService () {
  console.log('init service #' + Date.now());

  this.reset = () => {
    MyService();
  }
}
```

**Then you can use it everywhere like**

```
var myService = $injector.get('MyService');
myService.reset();
```

---

*With ES6 classes you can do something like this:*

```
class MyService {

  constructor() {
    console.log('init service #' + Date.now());

    this.reset = () => {
      new MyService();
    }
  }
}
```